# Python Django - Passing 2 Parameters To View - NoReverseMatch at /malware/

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x, url

So I am creating an application in Django. I am passing 1 parameter fine in other parts of the application however when adding two i think i get the regex wrong.

This is the part of the url.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<uuid>(\d+))/(?P<malware>(\d+))/$', views.execute, name='execute'),
```

This is the html file:

```
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="{% url 'execute' malware=malware uuid=uuid %}">    {{ vm }}</a></li>
```

This is the error:

```
Reverse for 'execute' with keyword arguments '{'uuid': '2932b679-787a-48e0-a4f7-be020b8e4734', 'malware': 'calc.exe'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<uuid>(\\d+))/(?P<malware>(\\d+))/$']
```

I am assuming this error is due to the regex. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit:

This is fixed - with the following string

```
url(r'^(?P<uuid>([0-9\-a-f]+))/(?P<malware>[a-z.]+)/$', views.execute, name='execute'), is the working string, perfect5th you've been an absolute kingpin here, thanks! – dipl0 8 hours ago
```

Comment: perfect5th, thank you,     url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w\-]+)$', views.transfer, name='transfer'), is a working regex so i'll try and emulate that

Comment: url(r'^(?P<uuid>([0-9\-a-f]+))/(?P<malware>[a-z.]+)/$', views.execute, name='execute'),
is the working string, perfect5th you've been an absolute kingpin here, thanks!

Comment: always glad to help. I've copied my comments into an answer, so I'll remove them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a malware value that is `\d+` (all digits), but passing in the value `'calc.exe'`. Try changing your regex pattern to match all expected values. Maybe `[a-z.]+`?

Likewise, your `<uuid>` pattern should probably be more like `[0-9\-a-f]+`.